# Docker volume mapping to current working directory not work

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-volume

Docker version 20.10.21

docker run command with -v option works as expected when the destination path is other than **/app**. But  when the destination path is **/app** it doesn't work as expected.

command works as expected:

```
  docker run -d  -v ${pwd}:/app2 react-app
```

command not works as expected:

```
docker run -d  -v ${pwd}:/app react-app
```

as seen in the snapshot there is not port for the second container
[image]

here is Dockerfile content

```
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13
RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app
WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir data
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
ENV API_URL=http://api.myapp.com/
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Maybe it replaces the content....app is you app folder and we you mount the volume on that same folder, volumme maybe overwrites that and your aspp code is gone?

Comment: @Hackerman I need to share source code to the container. So if that is the problem how can I share the source code without overwriting that thank you.

Comment: Please note the `dockerfile EXPOSE` statement does not automatically make the container listen on port 3000. You still need to add `-p 3000:3000` to `docker run` command. Other than that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75212969/1374322

Comment: So called `bind mounts` (and you are creating such a mount) are working slower than normal docker volumes. So you would probably want to minimize the number of files shared with container this way. A good option might be to mount only `src` folder, or even individual files.

Comment: What is the current directory name?  (Is there a space in it?)  You shouldn't need to mount anything into your container at all, the image already has all of the source code and installed dependencies in it.

Answer (score 2):

You are running `npm install` in `/app` in the Dockerfile, but then at runtime you are mounting `pwd` over the files you installed in `/app` during the build process. Don't install your dependencies in `/app` during the build if you want to mount to `/app` at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, you are right when I exec shell to the container mounted to app2, the node_modules is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using `$(pwd)` instead of `${pwd}`. Also if you are running it under Windows then you probably need to use some shell which implements `pwd` command correctly. E.g. `Git Bash`.

```
docker run -d  -v $(pwd):/app react-app
```

Also once you start the container please check `docker container inspect <container ID>`, specifically `Mounts` section.
Or you can filter the output:

```
 docker container inspect <container ID> -f '{{ .Mounts }}'
```

Also if you see that container exits immediately, please check its logs with

```
docker logs <container ID>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by excluding the **node_modules** from the mounting as:

```
docker run -d  -v ${pwd}:/app -v /app/node_modules  react-app
```

If the port not mapped to the host in the dockerfile use this:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -v ${pwd}:/app -v /app/node_modules  react-app
```